# SQLDF Update ignoring the Update

Tags: r, sqldf

I am running into an issue where I am calling sqldf to conduct an update on an added row. I have read the sqldf documentation and followed their examples, and no warnings beyond the normal "must utilize dbExecute()" appear. However, it ignores the update no matter how I change the statement even for something very simple.

````
```{r}
df$DiscPric = 0
head(df,5)

sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total*0.9 Where NumOfItems >= 5"))
sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total Where NumOfItems < 5"))
```;
````

Below are the data frames created before the alter, the new column added, and the update. I don't know if the syntax is wrong but it is not flagging it. When I tried to switch to a simpler update such as "UPDATE df SET Total = 0 Where InvoiceId = 1" it ignores this simple update as well

[image: First DataFrame Before alter in R]

[image: After New Column is Added]

[image: After Update is Applied].com/7wy3q.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqldf` does not update the variable in R, it just imports the data into sqlite and then processes. If you want the update to *replace* the R's version of `df`, you need to run two queries and overwrite `df`.

Something like:

```
df$DiscPric = 0
head(df,5)

DF <- sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total*0.9 Where NumOfItems >= 5",
              "SELECT * from main.df"))
DF <- sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total Where NumOfItems < 5",
              "SELECT * from main.df"))
```

or perhaps more succinctly:

```
df$DiscPric = 0
head(df,5)

DF <- sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total*0.9 Where NumOfItems >= 5",
              "UPDATE main.df SET DiscPric = Total Where NumOfItems < 5",
              "SELECT * from main.df"))
```

or using `case when ... then ... end` (a SQL function):

```
df$DiscPric = 0
head(df,5)

DF <- sqldf(c("UPDATE df SET DiscPric = Total * (case when NumOfItems >= 5 then 0.9 else 1 end)",
              "SELECT * from main.df"))
```

See https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#8-why-am-I-having-problems-with-update for some more explanation (scroll down to the 8th heading, the link doesn't always take you there within github).

Note that the `main.` is *required* within the second (and subsequent) query (and must not be in the first query). Without it, `sqldf` in the second query will pull `df` from the R environment again, ignoring the updates from the first query. `main.` is sqlite's database name, so it is telling sqlite/`sqldf` to use the already-present table in its schema.

---

In a pinch, though, you can do this directly in R without `sqldf`, in case this is not a simplified example:

```r
x$DiscPric <- x$Total * ifelse(x$NumOfItems >= 5, 0.9, 1)
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly it The third example with then and end worked best! though weirdly enough the first one where you showed the example split in two actually didn't work for my end and I received the error "x is not in the table"

Comment: Glad the third worked, not sure about the first error ... just updated the second with a `main.df` missed reference.